# configure mongodb only accept remote connection comes from LAN

Tags: mongodb

mongodb has bind ip but it is not so practical due to when new server add, it need shutdown db and add the new server ip into bind ip list and restart db. This is unacceptable because all other servers need to relaunch either.

In almost all deployment, servers machine and db machine are in same LAN. So can mongodb be configured as only accept ranges of ip of [172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255], [192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255], [10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255]?

These 3 ranges ip is LAN ip

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**bindIp** can accept multiple comma separated values. See the "Security considerations" section [Here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/configuration/)

Other than that you might want to consider configuring your firewall, maybe iptables if it runs on Linux machine.

Hope this helps

Comment: I can not predict the future new ip in LAN. If input all ip in those 3 ranges, it is too much to do that. iptables can do this, thanks

Comment: `bind_ip` is configuration for the address(es) that `mongod` listens to, not the remote addresses that are allowed to connect.

Answer (score 4):

The [`bind_ip` configuration value](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp) only determines which IP address(es) your MongoDB server is listening to. It does *not* control access from remote IPs -- that is the job of a [firewall](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-linux-iptables-firewall/).

The address ranges you have listed as requiring remote access are all [private IP address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces) which means these networks are not directly reachable/routable outside your LAN. Assuming you can route traffic between your private networks you should not need to bind to multiple IP addresses.

Given you are allowing access from a broad range of IP addresses, you should also read the [Security](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/security/) section of the MongoDB manual (in particular, the [Security Checklist](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/security-checklist/) and tutorial on enabling [Access Control](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/)).

Comment: Please, could you clarify your first two sentences? It seems like a contradiction to me.

From what I understand, the firewall and the `bind_ip` mechanisms are two consecutive sieves. There is a redundancy between the two. But still, unless an IP address not present in the set defined by `bind_ip` can access the database server, the `bind_ip` configuration *does* control access from remote IPs. What am I missing?

Comment: @MartinDrozdik The intent was to describe that the `bind_ip` value determines which local network IP address(es) a MongoDB server is *listening* to, but does not directly control ranges of remote IP addresses that are able to connect. A misconception in the original question is that remote IPs should be added to the `bind_ip` list: that security measure is the domain of a firewall, which could restrict network access to specific source IPs/CIDRs. Without a firewall, any client that can route traffic to an IP in the `bind_ip` list can attempt to connect.